# Is it possible to enforce CSS1 in browsers?

Tags: browser, css

I was recently surprised to learn that CSS2+ is Turing complete, and hence it is potentially dangerous, from the information security standpoint, to open websites containing CSS. That being said, if a corporate policy, for example, has a strict requirement to ensure a system as secure as reasonably possible, it would be necessary to only allow CSS not more recent than version 1. It is possible to turn off CSS altogether in a particular browser, but then most websites would become visually hardly usable (add this to the corporate policy requirement of having JS disabled as well).

All this being said, is it possible to disable all CSS2+ in a browser, while allowing the browser to still render CSS1 code?

Comment: Even at CSS1 level most websites would become visually hardly usable. I'm pretty convinced that browsers have this already sorted out and will stop CSS evaluation once something nefarious starts to happen.

Comment: Turing-complete in the sense that the user can press tab-enter-tab-enter-tab-enter-tab-enter-... and simulate a Turing machine using CSS to guide them to the next box that has to be ticked.

Comment: @user253751 HTML in conjunction with CSS2+ make a programming language with the capability to implement any possible algorithm with it (likewise, JS is also Turing complete). More on this: https://accodeing.com/blog/2015/css3-proven-to-be-turing-complete

Comment: @sequence only if the user presses tab-enter-tab-enter-tab-enter-... and CSS merely guides the user to tick the correct box.

Answer (score 4):

CSS2 was created in 1998, when websites were very rudimentary.
It is logical to assume that almost all websites nowadays use CSS options
that were developed after that date, which is after all already 24 years
behind us.

Most websites today use CSS3, currently supported on all major browsers.
Remember that CSS3 is not a set of additions to CSS2, it replaces CSS2.
Turning CSS3 off would just simply leave you with no CSS at all,
for all websites that use it.

CSS achieves its Turing completeness by incorporating JavaScript.
All major browsers today are heavily protected against JavaScript attacks,
to the point of executing in a sandbox without the ability to modify
the running system.

In my opinion, there is no danger in using CSS.
At least no more than the general danger when surfing the internet.
Be careful, and you have nothing to fear.

Comment: While javascript is still inherently dangerous, the mitigations you would use for it are entirely different than what you might do to restrict CSS interpretation, so completely agree with you.  Its likely anything you did regarding CSS would leave javascript execution as-is. Perhaps OP should look into NoScript.

Comment: @FrankThomas I would assume that one who was to disable CSS would also have disabled JS.